# .htaccess redirect /abc/def/ to /abc/def but not URLs starting with /xxx/yyy/?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this in .htaccess to redirect `/abc/def/` to `/abc/def`, removing trailing slash:

```
# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]
```

Which works well. Now I want to exclude URLs starting with `/xxx/yyy/` to NOT be redirected by the above rule, e.g. `/xxx/yyy/12345/` which need to stay as it is **without** being redirected to `/xxx/yyy/12345`, retaining trailing slash.

So I have:

```
# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/xxx/yyy/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]
```

But it doesn't work as `/xxx/yyy/12345/` is still being redirected to `/xxx/yyy/12345`. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Nothing seems wrong there. Are there other directives in your .htaccess?

Answer (score 0):

Use `THE_REQUEST` variable instead of `REQUEST_URI` as `REQUEST_URI` may change due to execution of other rules:

```
# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !\s/+xxx/yyy/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301,NE]
```

Make sure to use a new browser for testing.

Answer (score 0):

It seems it's because I have this in a .htaccess:

```
# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
```

In one of the upper directory. So what I have to use is this:

```
# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/xxx/yyy/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]
```

Adding `/public/` before `/xxx/yyy/` though the public URL is actually `/xxx/yyy/`.